# Way of executing several .sql files at once in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have around 100 .sql files that create stored procs. I'd like to execute them at once all of them.

They are contained inside a folder called `Stored Procedures`. There several other folders with different names --Table names-- inside the `Stored Procedures` folder.

Is there a way to execute all these files at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the another tool **[Sql_Server_Script_Executor](http://www.xsqlsoftware.com/Product/Sql_Server_Script_Executor.aspx)**

> Is there a way to execute all these
>   files at once?

***You can add folder and all your files will comes up in the list.  Click the execute button and done!!!!!!!!!!!!! ***

It contains three transaction modes.

```
1. Execute scripts within one transaction
2. Execute scripts on separate transaction
3. No transaction
```

and many more features please go through it.

[image]

Comment: I ended up using this. It even has a feature to create a batch command, so you can run it from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

You could open up a `PowerShell` instance and run a command like the following:

```
Get-ChildItem ".\Stored Procedures\*.sql" | ForEach-Object { sqlcmd -S ServerName -d DatabaseName -E -i $_.FullName }
```

This will get each .sql file in the Stored Procedures directory, and one by one, pass it to the sqlcmd.exe program. To get more details on the parameters for sqlcmd you can run `sqlcmd /?`.

To make it recursive through sub directories, you can apply the `-Recurse` parameter to `Get-ChildItem` along with the -Filter parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem '.\Stored Procedures' -Filter *.sql -Recurse | ForEach-Object { sqlcmd -S ServerName -d DatabaseName -E -i $_.FullName }
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it recursive? I mean, to get all sql scripts that insede folders inside `Stored Procedures` folder.

Comment: @tou - to recurse you can add the -Recurse parameter to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thats great, but how can i be sure that the scripts are executed in the right order (tables first, views second... functions, procedures, triggers and so on)?

Comment: @Ice - I would recommend putting the different script types in different folders and running across the above command across the folders sequentially. This would mean, placing table scripts in a **Table** folder, placing view scripts in a **Views** folder, etc. I've actually done this and is how I can create a database from scratch. If need be I can update the answer with a more detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

Not *at once* - but all in one go - try a tool like the [SSW Deploy](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/SQLDeploy/) one.

[image]

Comment: @tou: you didn't require free - and good software does cost - but it's worth its price - SQL Deploy **is"" worth its price - many times over :-)