# How to deploy no of stored procedures in database using SSIS task?

Tags: ssis-2012

How to i deploy(run) all my stored procedures in database using ssis tasks.For example
I have around 800 newly created stored procedures stored in separate folder.I want to run(F5)all these store procedures from my folder.Not required to execute the procedure.

It will take much time If I open each stored procedure manually and Press F5 Button in IDE:-).

Is there any automation process to achieve this in SSIS ?

Answer (score 0):

Why SSIS? If you are not specific about SSIS then you can run all of the stored procedure at once using DOS command like below

(taken from [This Post](https://superuser.com/questions/206678/script-to-run-all-sql-files-in-a-particular-folder))

```
for %%f in (*.sql) do sqlcmd -U<User> -P<Pass> -S<Server> -d<Database> -i%%f
```

(OR)

You can write a script file (*.sql) and include call to each procedure like

```
use [DBNAME]
GO

exec proc1

exec proc2

...

exec procn
```

Then run it thorugh `SQLCMD` command line utility like

```
sqlcmd -U<User> -P<Pass> -S<Server> -i <script file name>
```

As well take a look at this post

[Way of executing several .sql files at once in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344963/way-of-executing-several-sql-files-at-once-in-sql-server)

Comment: SqlCmd command is fine.But I am looking forward SSIS kind of approach.

Comment: Every month I am getting the these many changes to incorporate all in one db is big challange.So would be better if we create a SSIS package to schedule it as job in sqlserver agent.